# JS to PHP Sockets?

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, websocket

I have become very comfortable with PHP and mySQL over the past couple months, but I have recently wanted to create a game (with database connections) that needs even better responsiveness then AJAX. This is where I came across sockets. I do not want to branch into Node.js (I am more comfortable with PHP servers) but PHP sockets can't be pushed information via JavaScript, which is crucial for responsive user input.

In short, I am seeking a method with the responsiveness of sockets but that can be pushed by the client in JS and received in PHP on server, similar to AJAX but bidirectional and fast.

Note I may be misunderstanding some of these concepts as a new member to this crazy new set of servers. Just correct and direct me please.

Comment: There's no such thing as JS Sockets or PHP Sockets.  There are network sockets and such, but it sounds like you're asking about Web Sockets which is a layer on top of HTTP... not a normal network socket at all.  What are you trying to do exactly?  What specifically do you mean by "responsiveness"?

Comment: @Brad I am looking to make a connection between the server and the client that is faster than AJAX and doesn't require the client to constantly poll the server to see if their is more information it needs. Ideally for a game.

Comment: Web Sockets is what you're looking for, in that case.  And yes, you can write the server in PHP.  There are many Web Socket packages available for PHP.

If you were only streaming data in one direction, a normal HTTP request is fine.  You could even use something like the SSE API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build a PHP websocket server, Take a look at RatchetPHP: http://socketo.me/

It uses a sub protocol, WAMP so your websocket connection will have channels (topics).

Cons: It still uses the version 1 of WAMP subprotocol, the author suggest to use Thruway.

But RatchetPHP is better documented, and let you learn to implement websockets easily.